# Open Graph Metatags for every URL instead of page

Tags: angularjs, ajax, phantomjs, single-page-application, facebook-opengraph

I have developed a page similar to facebook wall which have list of post in Angular (SPA). Every post have unique url to reach exactly to that post. I am new to open graph metatags. I have inserted metatags in head tag.

```
 <meta property="og:url" content="#####"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="####"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="######"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="/images/####.png"/>
```

**The meta tags are common for every post, how to assign meta tags for every url (post)?**

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it as per suggested in this [blog](https://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app)

1. I built a non-public, minimal jsp page with all og tags necessary. OG Tags were generated after query database, so they are dynamic.

   ```
           <!doctype html>
               <html lang="en">


                   <head>
                       <sql:query dataSource="jdbc/localMysql" var="result">
                           ---- Query -------
                       </sql:query>
                       <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                           <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
                           <meta name= "twitter:card" content="summary" />
                           <meta name= "twitter:site" content="@#####" />
                           <meta property="og:title" content='<c:out value=" ${row.######} "/>' />
                           <meta name="og:description" content='<c:out value=" ${Jsoup.parse(row.######).text()} "/>' />
                           <meta name="twitter:card" content='<c:out value=" ${Jsoup.parse(row.######).text()} "/>' />
                           <c:if test="${not empty row.#####}">
                               <meta property="og:image" content='/UserImages/<c:out value=" ${fn:trim(row.####)} "/>' />
                               <meta name= "twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
                           </c:if>
                       </c:forEach>
                   </head>

                   <body>

                   </body>

               </html>
   ```
2. I have built a crawler detection module using tuckey urlrewrite, if its user I show normal page while if its crawler a non public jsp page is shown.

   ```
   <rule>
       <condition name="user-agent" next="or">facebookexternalhit/*
   </condition>
       <condition name="user-agent" next="or">Facebot</condition>
       <condition name="user-agent">Twitterbot/*</condition>
       <from>/wall/*</from>
       <set name="postUrl">$1</set>
       <to>/crawler-index.jsp</to>
   </rule>
   <rule>
       <from>/wall/*</from>
       <to>/index.jsp</to>
   </rule>
   ```