# Facebook OG crawler showing error

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-opengraph

I am developing OG module in my app. Below is URL which is working fine with twitter and whasapp however showing issue with facebook.

http://nvie.in/portal/gyany/product/145

[image]

[image]

This is what facebook crawler see in my page-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://nvie.in/crawler-products-page.jsp">
</head>
<body>

                </body>
</html>
```

This is my code

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
        <%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix = "fn" %>
        <%@ page import="org.jsoup.*" %>

            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
            <%
                String appVersion= "1";
                String portalId= request.getAttribute("portalId").toString();

                String requestProtocol=request.getScheme();
                String requestDomain=request.getServerName();
                String requestPort=Integer.toString(request.getServerPort());

                String requestBasePath = requestProtocol+"://"+requestDomain+":"+requestPort;
            %>

                <head>

                    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
                    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />

                    <link rel="canonical" href="<%=(request.getRequestURL().toString())%>">

                    <sql:query dataSource="jdbc/localMysql" var="result">
                        --- Query to fetch portal details---= '<%=portalId %>';
                    </sql:query>
                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">

                        <meta property="og:url" content="<%=(request.getRequestURL().toString())%>" />
                        <meta name= "twitter:card" content="summary" />
                        <meta name= "twitter:site" content="@####" />
                        <meta property="og:title" content='<c:out value=" ${row.portal_name} "/>' />
                        <meta property="og:description" content='<c:out value=" ${Jsoup.parse(row.portal_tagline).text()} "/>' />

                        <c:if test="${not empty row.file_url}">
                            <meta property="og:image" content='<%=requestBasePath%>/####/<c:out value="${fn:trim(row.file_url)}"/>' />
                            <meta name= "twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                </head>

                <body>

                </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: Well if you specify `<link rel="canonical" href="http://nvie.in/crawler-products-page.jsp">`, then Facebook will request _that_ URL and try to find the meta data there. Why do you have that set to a different URL that delivers totally different content (which as of now seems to be rather nothing, an empty page) in the first place?

Comment: I have different page for crawlers only with meta tags and regular page for other users. I had to do that because my app is built in angular and crawlers can't extract javascript og tags. See this question of mine- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724048/open-graph-metatags-for-every-url-instead-of-page

Comment: I have removed link tab as suggested by you and its still not working, now it stopped working for twitter too :(

Comment: Well right now the FB scraper can not even read your page, _"Could Not Connect To Server: Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers."_